# How to add an element at an index in singly linked list in C#

Tags: c#, data-structures, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I am implementing linked-list data-structure in C#. I am facing below issue.

When I am try to add element at an index in singly linked list then it not working.

below is my code. Issue is in function AddToIndex. It is not working properly.

Node

```
public class DNode
{
    public int data;
    public DNode next;
    public DNode(int d)
    {
        data = d;
    }
}
```

LinkedList

```
public class DLinkedList
{
    public int data;
    public DNode Next { get; set; }
    public DNode Head { get; private set; }
    public DNode Tail { get; private set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }
    public void AddToHead(int element)
    {
        DNode temp = new DNode(element);
        temp.next = Head;
        Head = temp;
        Count++;
        if (Count == 1)
        {
            Tail = Head;
        }
    }
    public void AddToIndex(int element, int index)
    {
        DNode temp = new DNode(element);
        for (int i = 1; i < index - 1; i++)
        {
            Head = Head.next;
        }
        temp.next = Head;//in this case infinite link list
        //temp.next = Head.next; in this case one element is removed.
        Head.next = temp; // whole link list is not created, partial linked list created
    }

    public void Display()
    {
        DNode temp = Head;
        while (temp != null)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine(temp.data);
            temp = temp.next;
        }
    }
}
```

To display result set

```
static class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DLinkedList dLinked = new DLinkedList();
        dLinked.AddToHead(5);
        dLinked.AddToHead(7);
        dLinked.AddToHead(10);
        dLinked.AddToHead(11);
        Console.WriteLine("---Add Head---");
        dLinked.Display();
        dLinked.AddToIndex(12, 4);
        Console.WriteLine("---After AddToIndex function");
        dLinked.Display();

    }
}
```

Result on Console: 
---Add Head---
11
10
7
5
---After AddToIndex function Called --
7
12
5

Note: I am just building this no test cases is run .

Comment: [LinkedList<T>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.linkedlist-1?view=netframework-4.8) Datatype already exists in C#, why create an own implementation?

Comment: You are changing head : Head = Head.next;  You need a new DNode xNode.  Then set xNode = Head before you go into for loop.

Comment: You need to preserve previous node in the loop so that its next can be set to the new node. Also you don't seem to handle the case where a new head is inserted.

Comment: @MindSwipe  I am learning data-structure.

Comment: Single-step your code in the debugger and examine the values of the variables at each step. That will help you understand how code works. If you don't know how to use the debugger, now is the perfect time to learn. It will save you uncountable hours of frustration.

Answer (score 0):

you are modifying the head of the linked list, which should not be done. try taking another temp variable and assign it to head. like the code below.

```
       public void AddToIndex(int element, int index)
        {
            DNode temp = new DNode(element);
            DNode temp1=Head;
            for (int i = 1; i < index - 1; i++)
            {
                temp1 = temp1.next;
            }
            temp.next=temp1.next
            temp1.next=temp            
        }
```